# Getting undefined in Post request

Tags: php, postgresql, post, get

```
  <script>
function updateClient(){
            $id= $("#btnsend").val();
        //alert("la funcion ejecuta");
           if ($("#cliente_nom").val()==""){
            alert("Ingrese NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE.");
            }
            else{
                $.post("controllers/editclientController.php",
                { 

                    id_cliente: $id,
                    nom_clie: $('#cliente_nom').val(),
                    contact: $('#contacto').val(),
                    dir_com: $('#direc_com').val(),
                    telefono: $('#telef').val(),
                    cedula: $('#cedula').val(),
                    ruc: $('#ruc').val(),
                    zone: $('#zona').val(),
                    ciudad: $('#ciudad').val(),
                    fax: $('#fax').val(),
                    tipo: $('#tipo').val(),
                    telefono_dom: $('#telef_dom').val()

                ,

                function(data, status){

                alert("Informacion \nDATA:"+data+"\nSTATUS="+status);


                }

                }
                );





}
}
</script>
```

The following function is returning "data" and "status" both as undefined. What could be the problem? I tried commenting the individual fields and it still presents the same issue. Could it be a syntax error? or does it have to do with the html fields itself?

Comment: where is your PHP code?

Comment: I solved it! is just that i am starting to program on php,/postgresql and having some troubles learning these. The problem was that one of my brackets was below the function thus, the post method was not executing correctly